# How to fix Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null in javascript in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, console

```js
const printSentence = (id, sentence, speed = 50) => {
  let index = 0;
  let element = document.getElementById(id);
  
  let timer = setInterval(function() {
    const char = sentence[index];
    
    if (char === '<') {
      index = sentence.indexOf('>', index);  // skip to greater-than
    }
    
    element.innerHTML = sentence.slice(0, index);
    
    if (++index === sentence.length) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, speed);
} // printSentence

printSentence(
  'one',
  '<h2>Wordpress</h2>',
  50
);
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
```

But I see an error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

I tried `window.onload` but it doesn't work
Any tip of how to fix this problem in console?

Comment: what is `id` - what does your html look like

Comment: There's no element with id `one` when you call `printSentence('one', ...)`. How are we supposed to fix this?

Comment: No I just forgot I have a div with id one

Comment: My comment is still valid. When you call `printSentence('one', ...)` there's is no element with that id in the DOM. Otherwise `.getElementById('one')` wouldn't return `null`

Comment: you can see the above snippet the console in google chrome in my wordpress website show error but in the console of stackoverflow snippet it doesn't show any error

Answer (score -1):

#### The error message is telling you that ELEMENT is null

This means that `let element = document.getElementById(id);` is returning null. (Add a console.log of element, to check, if you like).

Most likely reason for this is that there is no tag with id "one".

#### Look at the HTML of the page on which this is being run

Make sure that it has a tag with id "one".
The commonest reason for getting into this situation is that the DOM doesn't contain the element with id "one" at the time the javascript is running.

That is why it is best to use the [image] icon to enter your code so that it can be replicated easily by others.

#### Now we have your snippet, it seems to be working correctly

It is showing a slowly-appearing text in the output window. In the console log, I am seeing an irrelevant error message, perhaps something to with security.

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at Object.vAPI.bootstrap (chrome-extension://cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm/js/contentscript.js:1755:46)
    at chrome-extension://cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm/js/contentscript.js:1764:6
```

If it is working for you too, but you are concerned about *your* error message that you described, why don't you do this:

Change

```
element.innerHTML = sentence.slice(0, index);
```

to

```
if(element){
  element.innerHTML = sentence.slice(0, index);
} else {
  console.log("Cannot do element.innerHTML. The current value of element is ",element,". Index is currently ",index)
}
```

Comment: I have a div with id one

Comment: You think you have, but it is not present in the DOM at the time the Javascript is running. Use the "<>" icon in Stack Overflow's editor to add your code, both HTML and Javascript, so that we can replicate it.

Comment: Thank u you can see the above snippet please ??

Comment: Ah, I see the problem is in WordPress, not in the JS or HTML. Can you now see, that the original commenters were correct? There was nothing wrong with the code that you originally showed, or even are currently showing. That is why it is vital to provide a reproducible runnable piece of code, and not just a screenshot or description.   Try the last section I have added in my answer, and report back what you see. Maybe Wordpress is doing something strange with timing, or names of things? The code I added will help you identify what Wordpress is doing to your program.